# Which film had "See something, say something" billboard with Muslim woman's face?

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Around the early 2000s, early in the G.W. Bush administration I believe, I saw a US theatrical release of a feature-length dystopian film set in a slightly near-future UK. I think there were dissidents/"terrorists," a train, a secret camp, a car chase, an ambush along a tree-heavy rural roadway, and a bomb, IIRC. I remember my contemporaries being a little surprised that the film could get away with its commentary on the nature of the "War on Terror," and a sentiment that the UK setting made it more acceptable to an American audience.

The main image that stuck in my mind was a dark coloured red and black billboard at a train station featuring a close-up of a Muslim woman's veiled face and some "See something, say something"-like exhortation. I think the photo may have been subtly live in the manner of the 'wanted' posters in the Harry Potter films.

Any clues as to the identity of the film? Thank you.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're referring to [real life](http://kennethfranqueiro.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/oc-ssss.jpg)

Comment: @Richard Obviously, the respectable, clothed penguin should report the publicly indecent penguins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Children of Men* was set in a near-future UK and had 'dissidents/"terrorists," a train, a secret camp, a car chase, an ambush along a tree-heavy rural roadway, and a bomb'. I don't remember the billboard, but it may well have been in there.

Here's the scene with the ambush along the rural roadway, which was memorable for its use of a single uninterrupted take:

I also found a video collecting various advertisements and propaganda videos created to appear in the background, and at 44 seconds in there's a picture of a woman who looks like she's probably either arab or south asian (no veil), her image then shrinks into a group of other faces and "report all illegal immigrants" appears over them in bright red letters:

Could that be what you're remembering?

Comment: Thank you!! I'm confident enough that you've got bingo that I've accepted it. I'll watch it soon to be sure (and to finally see this good film again!).

Comment: I've been searching for ten years -- I even married a librarian to increase my odds. She said today that she already said CoM twice and I somehow convinced myself otherwise. More to follow...

Of course Michael Caine would be in it.